# Using "on" method to define multiple events for multiple selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
let test = function (e) {
    if (e.type === 'click' || e.which === 13) {
        console.log($('input[type=text]').val());
    }
};

$(document).on('keyup', 'input[type=text]', test);
$(document).on('click', 'button', test);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
<button>test</button>
```

I want to combine the lines:

```
$(document).on('keyup', 'input[type=text]', test);
```

and

```
$(document).on('click', 'button', test);
```

to one line, like this (for writing code faster):

```
$(document).on('keyup, click', 'input[type=text], button', test);
```

But I don't want to set the `onclick` event for the `input` selector, same to the `keyup` event for the `button` selector.

Is there a way to do that? Thank you!

Comment: Sorry but... why?

Comment: @IaconisSimone `(for writing code faster)`

Comment: @foo Good code is better than "faster written" code.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense, you can save 2 second of writing but thne you would need 2 more minutes to understand it in thw future, that's not readable

Comment: Make smart Code but make it sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The closest you can come is:

```
$(document).on('keyup', 'input[type=text]', test)
           .on('click', 'button', test);
```

...which obviously isn't much of a change compared to your first version.

Because you want to hook separate (delegated) events on separate elements, you have to make separate `on` calls.

---

If you want, of course, you can give yourself a plugin to do it:

```
$.fn.onAll = function(spec) {
    Object.keys(spec).forEach(key => {
        this.on(key, ...spec[key]);
    });
    return this;
};
```

That specific one would be used like this:

```
$(document).onAll({
  keyup: ['input[type=text]', test],
  click: ['button', test]
});
```

...which doesn't seem like a coding savings, but perhaps you could come up with something more concise. :-)

Live example:

```js
$.fn.onAll = function(spec) {
    Object.keys(spec).forEach(key => {
        this.on(key, ...spec[key]);
    });
    return this;
};

let test = function (e) {
    if (e.type === 'click' || e.which === 13) {
        console.log($('input[type=text]').val());
    }
};

$(document).onAll({
  keyup: ['input[type=text]', test],
  click: ['button', test]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
<button>test</button>
```

Or using the same handler for all of the events:

```
$.fn.onAny = function(events, handler) {
    Object.keys(events).forEach(key => {
        this.on(key, events[key], handler);
    });
    return this;
};
```

Used like:

```
$(document).onAny({
  keyup: 'input[type=text]',
  click: 'button'
}, test);
```

Live example:

```js
$.fn.onAny = function(events, handler) {
    Object.keys(events).forEach(key => {
        this.on(key, events[key], handler);
    });
    return this;
};

let test = function (e) {
    if (e.type === 'click' || e.which === 13) {
        console.log($('input[type=text]').val());
    }
};

$(document).onAny({
  keyup: 'input[type=text]',
  click: 'button'
}, test);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
<button>test</button>
```

---

Side note: Old habits! I could have used

```
for (const key of Object.keys(spec /* or `events`*/)) {
    // ...
}
```

...instead of using `forEach` in each of the above.

Comment: Many thanks! And...... my sub question is: How does my question become a bad question? I just want to know is there another way to define the events? As you can see, someone know that, someone not (1 answer gets -2 and 1 answer was deleted.)

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by checking the event type and the active element.

```js
$(document).on('keyup click', 'input[type=text], button', function(e) {
  var $this = $(this);
  var eventType = e.type;
  if (e.type=='click' && $this.is('button')) {
    console.log('click + button');
  }
  else if (e.type=='keyup' && $this.is('input[type=text]')) {
    console.log('keyup + input[type=text]');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
<button>click!</button>
```

I would personally very much prefer to just split them up though. It's less code and much easier to read.

```
$(document)
  .on('click', 'button', function() {
    console.log('click + button');
  })
  .on('keyup', 'input[type=text]', function() {
    console.log('keyup + input[type=text]');
  });
```

Comment: Another viable alternative. More work in the handler, but there was already logic in the handler to differentiate the events, so... (No need for the call to `is` but that is the jQuery way; I'd just use `this.tagName === "BUTTON"`.)

Comment: You're right about `is`. I might have over-jQueried (yes, I just made a new word) it there ;)

Answer (score 1):

Well, TJ Crowder already has an excellent answer regarding the subject (I'd prefer it that way), but if you want it really how you described it you can do it like this:

```js
function test() {
  $("#log").append("Fire<br>");
}

function registerEvents(input, elements, callback) {
  var inputarr = input.split(","),
    elementarr = elements.split(","),
    $document = $(document); // Caching

  for (var i = 0, j = input.length; i < j; i++) {
    $document.on(inputarr[i].trim(), elementarr[i].trim(), callback);
  }
}

registerEvents('keyup, click', 'input[type=text], button', test);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Text Here" />
<button>Click me</button>

<p id="log"></p>
```

Answer (score -2):

It will be more readable if you attach listeners directly, not via `$(document)`.

```
$('input[type=text]').keyup(test);
$('button').click(test);
```

Comment: 1. No, it won't. 2. Then they won't be delegated, which is presumably important. 3. This doesn't answer the question the OP asked.